# Why Download button is hidden in TED?

Tags: video, download, ted

I was able to download videos from TED simply by clicking on download button since couple days ago.

But suddenly it has been hidden now! [it was on the right hand]

[image]

So, How can I bring it back?

or there is another way to download these videos? [I tried ted downloader and Amara but I couldn't as well].

Answer (score 3):

Since you already know the name of the video you want to download, you can go to the [Ted Talks List](https://www.ted.com/talks/quick-list) and download it from there.

You can also use the [Ted Talks Downloader](https://bitbucket.org/obinshah/ted-talks-downloader/downloads/) to download multiple videos at once.

Answer (score 3):

They have hidden download links under "share" link :

https://support.ted.com/customer/portal/articles/2631608

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no information about downloading under the 'Share' button

Answer (score 0):

**The download link is now under the sharing options.**

Most likely most of the users weren't using it much, compared to the other more relevant buttons. And they wanted to clear the player a bit and make it look nicer.

It also makes sense to put it with the sharing options.

Answer (score 0):

If something like download button gets hidden from sight on a website (or completely removed) it's mostly because of increased interest in downloading content which means a decrease of a stay-traffic on the website. In general, it is always more prefered to browse the website, eg. stay on a website the great amount of time and watch media content 1 by 1, rather than jump in, download 10 videos simultaneously (which creates a huge peak of demand over a short period of time resulting on decrease of service a website can provide) and leave the site.

in 2019 it looks like this:

[image]