# Unable to Download TED video

Tags: video-download, ted

I am using the latest version of Firefox but am unable to download TED videos.

Firstly there is no download button visible anywhere on the page despite information on Google that there is a download option on the left of the screen.

Secondly, I found a tip at Amara saying that the download option has been altered and is hidden under the 'Share' button but when I press the 'share' button there is no information about downloading, only links to Facebook and the like.

Has the method of downloading changed again and, if so, how do I download videos?

Comment: can you link the video you trying to download?

Comment: *anywhere on the page* On what page? I think you mean ted.com, but then say so and give an example URL.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/why-download-button-is-hidden-in-ted

Answer (score 2):

- click on **Share**
- under **Tools** you will find **Download**

[image]